# Correct way to use cache() for PySpark RDD

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm having a hard time finding examples on how to cache RDDs in PySpark. Right now I'm doing something like this:

```
rdd2 = rdd1.map(...)
rdd2.cache()
foo = rdd2.collect()
bar = rdd2.count()
rdd2.unpersist()
...
```

I wonder if I am correctly caching rdd2, i.e. will rdd2.count() trigger another whole computation from the root RDD, or will rdd2.count() use the cached rdd2 from rdd1.map()?
Do I have to call the cache function after an action on rdd2 (like after collect()) or it doesn't matter?
Would appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Due to laziness of spark, cache triggers after action is applied (e.g. count(), collect()). So in your case rdd.cache() 'triggers' after the first action is called (`collect()`) and `count()` will use already cached RDD.

Answer (score -2):

`RDD.cache()` is for whole RDD, just need to be called once even for multiple actions.